# Show that $f'_n \rightarrow f'$ uniformly on every compact set.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assume that $f_n,f:D(0,1)\rightarrow C$ are holomorphic.
and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on every compact set.
we need to show that $f'_n \rightarrow f'$ uniformly on every compact set.

I kind of have no idea how to approach this one, its from a test I attended and I'm going for a second go at it and I want to understand the first one, first.

Comment: From Cauchy's formulas for the derivatives.